# How to calculate time difference of 2 datetime object in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am very new in AngularJS and  I want to calculate time difference between `two datetime object with format`:

> Hour:Minutes:Seconds

But I want to get double digit output in time :

> Expected Output: 00 : 00 : 04

**Input:**

```
StartDate=2016-06-29 15:52:32.360

EndDate=2016-06-29 15:53:36.970

Expected output: 00 : 01 : 04
```

This is my code:

```
public class User
{
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDateTime { get; set; }
      public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDateTime { get; set; }
}

Json output:

[
  {
    "Id": 121,
    "StartDateTime": "\/Date(1467195752360)\/",  //2016-06-29 15:52:32.360
    "EndDateTime": "\/Date(1467195756970)\/", //2016-06-29 15:53:36.970
  },
  {
    "Id": 122,
   "StartDateTime": "\/Date(1467195752360)\/",// 2016-06-29 15:52:32.360

    "EndDateTime": "\/Date(1467195758360)\/", //2016-06-29 15:53:36.970
  }
]
```

Code:

```
 <td  ng-repeat="item in User">
      //How to display time difference here
      <p> Hour : Minutes : Seconds  </p
  </td>
```

Comment: don't care about them. What you do to try this ?

Comment: How would you compare said dates in javascript?

Comment: is this your datetime is a string from bootstrap datetime or its returned from JavaScript date

Comment: @VivekSingh:This datetime is returned from server side method.you can consider web service

Comment: Ok I will tell you a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve it using filter in ng-repeat:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.timeSlots = [  
     {  
        "startDate":1467195752360,
        "endDate":1467195756970
     },
     {  
        "startDate":1467195752360,
        "endDate":1467195758360
     }
  ];
});

app.filter("getDiff", function() {
  return function(time) {
    var startDate = new Date(time.startDate);
    var endDate = new Date(time.endDate);
    var milisecondsDiff = endDate - startDate;
    
      return Math.floor(milisecondsDiff/(1000*60*60)).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2}) + ":" + (Math.floor(milisecondsDiff/(1000*60))%60).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2})  + ":" + (Math.floor(milisecondsDiff/1000)%60).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2}) ;
  
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
   <p ng-repeat = "time in timeSlots" ng-bind="time | getDiff">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How i can do this for each of my records as i am using ng repeat

Comment: Getting NAN in your plunker output

Comment: what dates are you using to test ? i tested with few dates and it looks fine

Comment: Same date i have used in my question but i am talking about your plunker.Check you plunker

Comment: this one correct? http://plnkr.co/edit/ORw3jenBOXAKwtN8bMo6?p=preview. I am getting this output 0:1:4 and 1:1:4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116490/discussion-between-deep-and-learning).

Comment: @Deep +1 This answer is concise and uses the AngularJS framework well.

Comment: ok now i am getting time but it is not double digit as what i am expecting double digit.I am getting like this:0:1:4 but i want like this : 00:01:04

Comment: your code is giving inappropriate secconds with this start and enddate:$scope.timeSlots = [{startDate:"2016-07-21 16:31:36.580",endDate:"2016-07-21 16:31:40.380"},{startDate:"2016-06-29 15:52:32.360",endDate:"2016-06-29 16:53:36.970"}]

Comment: Check out in this plunker created by you:http://plnkr.co/edit/ORw3jenBOXAKwtN8bMo6?p=preview

Comment: its displaying 00:00:03  and 01:01:04,the first value is 3 seconds because here the milliseconds value of startdate is greater than  enddate. let me know in case you were expecting something else

Comment: but output should be :00 : 00 : 04 right as because we have 4 seconds of difference in our starttime and endtime(16:31:36.580   vs    16:31:40.380)

Comment: OK, the current code take the floor value that is why the difference which is  3 second 800 milliseconds, displayed as 3 seconds. Do you want it to round up?

Comment: Yes because 3 seconds seems to be inappropriate because subtracting 31 40  from 31 36 output should be 00: 04 seconds right

Comment: here is the update plunker as per your requirement http://plnkr.co/edit/RCsMD3JgFtvvGb53lc5L?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117991/discussion-between-learning-and-deep).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "$filter" of angular to format the date to yours

a working plunker :  http://plnkr.co/edit/4QzT8688iQkIxoqnJVy0?p=preview

JS :

```
     // Declare the main module
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 angular.module('myApp').controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope','$filter',  function($scope,$filter) {


   $scope.dates = [
     {
       "Id": 121,
       "StartDateTime": 1467195752360,  //2016-06-29 15:52:32.360
       "EndDateTime": 1467195756970, //2016-06-29 15:53:36.970
     },
     {
       "Id": 122,
      "StartDateTime": 1467195752360, // 2016-06-29 15:52:32.360
       "EndDateTime": 1467195758360, //2016-06-29 15:53:36.970
     }
   ];

   var compute = function(dates)  {
     for (var i in dates){
       dates[i].hours = $filter('date')(dates[i]["EndDateTime"]-dates[i]["StartDateTime"], 'hh') ; 
       dates[i].minutes = $filter('date')(dates[i]["EndDateTime"]-dates[i]["StartDateTime"], 'mm') ;
       dates[i].secondes = $filter('date')(dates[i]["EndDateTime"]-dates[i]["StartDateTime"], 'ss') ;
     }

   }

   compute($scope.dates);


 }]);
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
       <div ng-repeat="date in dates">
  {{ date.hours }} :{{ date.minutes }} : {{date.secondes }}
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you show that how do i will use this with ng-repeat as this will be done insidee ng repeat

Comment: sorry i don't undersatand what you want. you want to to use an ng-repeat and to calcul it in view side ?

Comment: I am saying that i am getting list of records and i want to calculate difference of 2 datetime object for each records.You have done this for single record.Consider you have more than 1 records and you want to calculate time difference for each of this records then how you will do it??

Comment: So when i get my records in ajax success function so at that time i need to pass my User object in your compute function right???

Comment: Getting null:null:null

Answer (score 1):

Make a function in angular like this.

```
var timediff=function(){
var startdate=StartDate;//yr json date.
var enddate=EndDate;

// here we will split date time string to get date hour min sec invidually.
var arr=[];
arr=startdate.split(' ');//split date and time
date=arr[0];
var arr0=[];
arr0=date.split('-');//split date into yr,date, month

time=arr[1];
var arr1=[];
arr1=time.split(':');//split time into min , hour, sec

var datebegin = new Date(arr0[0], arr0[1]-1, arr0[2], arr1[0], arr1[1],arr1[2])

var arr=[];
arr=enddate.split(' ');
date=arr[0];
var arr0=[];
arr0=date.split('-');

time=arr[1];
var arr1=[];
arr1=time.split(':');

var dateend = new Date(arr0[0], arr0[1]-1, arr0[2], arr1[0], arr1[1],arr1[2])

var timeLeft =  dateend-datestart  ;
parseTime(timeLeft);




}
```

make parse function

```
 var parseTime=function(diff){

 var msec = diff;
 var hh = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60 / 60);
 msec -= hh * 1000 * 60 * 60;
 var mm = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60);
 msec -= mm * 1000 * 60;
 var ss = Math.floor(msec / 1000);
msec -= ss * 1000;

 $scope.hh=hh;
  $scope.mm=mm;
 $scope.ss=ss;
 }
```

use these scope variable in your code like this.

```
<p> {{hh}} : {{mm}} : {{ss}}</p>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to use it in my html view inside p tag for each record??

Comment: So when i get my records in ajax success function i loop in to that records and for each record call your function timediff and in this function i pass my startdate and enddate right??